# why deleteById follows a bidirectional approach?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

i have 2 entities where one entity has a manyToOne relationship with the second entity

entity 1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chilling_unit")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChillingUnitMonitoringDetailsDAO<T> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="edge_controller_serial_number",nullable = false)
  private String l3SerialNumber;

  @Column(name = "product_type_name")
  private String productType;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL
  @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  @JsonIgnore
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  private LocationDAO location;

}
```

and entity 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LocationDAO {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "location_id",unique = true)
  private String locId;

}
```

but whenever i try to execute the delete command using JPA respository i.e `deleteById(id)` the operation deletes both chlllingUnitMonitoringDetails and location

but it should only delete chlllingUnitMonitoringDetails row and not location, can anyone tell me why location is also deleted??

and how to prevent this??

```
public interface ChillingUnitMonitoringRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<ChillingUnitMonitoringDetailsDAO<T>,Long> {

}
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. `cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.WHAAAT`? Also, don't call your entities DAO. A DAO is a service allowing to execute queries returning or modifying entities.

Comment: Right, the `DAO` like things are `Repository` in spring data. You may name your `ChillingUnitMonitoringRepository` as `ChillingUnitMonitoringDAO` if you want to use the name DAO. You should name your entities as is(the object's name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` annotation above. This means "while a `ChillingUnitMonitoringDetailsDAO` is deleting, delete the `LocationDAO` also".

I recommend you do a little research about the cascade types.
You can start from here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

The delete operation will be cascaded also if you have `cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL` or `cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE` above the `Location` field.

Comment: so should i remove both `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` and `cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL ` ??

Comment: yes, because `CascadeType.ALL` contains `CascadeType.REMOVE` and causes cascading on delete

Comment: okay if i remove both they work, thanks.......though i'm tempted to use `cascase.merge` as it will update my db in case any change in chillingUnit, what do you think??

Comment: @Hummingbird if you put `CascadeType.MERGE` above the `private Location location;`, then any change on `ChillingUnitMonitoringDetails.location` will be ***merged*** when a `ChillingUnitMonitoringDetails` instance saved to database.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove row `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)`.

Comment: removing `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` did not do anything

Comment: Show your DDL-command for these tables. Are there cascading deletions? Or just execute native SQL-command in redactor (without JPA, only SQL) and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to remove cascading.

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id")

@JsonIgnore
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  private LocationDAO location;